# How to create a textbutton in Flash using ActionScript 3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

When I tried using a textfield as a button, it seems it is not having the `buttonMode` property.

How can I programatically create a text button using ActionScript in a Flash project.
It should be a simple text, which is clickable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the `TextField` to a `Sprite` and use it as the button. [buttonMode](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Sprite.html#buttonMode) is the property of `Sprite` class.

If you really want to use just a `TextField`, you can assign an anchor tag `<a href="event:something">label</a>` to its `htmlText` or listen to `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` events and show a custom hand cursor after hiding the default mouse pointer using `Mouse.hide()`

Comment: I think this will do. And we need to disable it going to the link upon clicking the link text mentioned in <a> tag also.. right?. 
Hope that can be handled in event listener.

Comment: `event:` syntax will cause a `TextEvent.LINK` event to be fired when you click, with `something` stored in the `text` property of event. You can handle the event or just ignore it - it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a TextField, set the text format as you wish, set selectable to false, etc.
If you want the hand cursor, just nest the textfield into a sprite, and set mouseChildren to false.

e.g.

```
var textButton:Sprite = getTextButton('Push Me!');
addChild(textButton);
textButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, function(event:MouseEvent){trace('click')});

function getTextButton(label:String):Sprite{
    var txt:TextField = new TextField();
    txt.defaultTextFormat = new TextFormat('Verdana',10,0x000000);
    txt.text = label;
    txt.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    txt.background = txt.border = true;
    txt.selectable = false;
    var btn:Sprite = new Sprite();
    btn.mouseChildren = false;
    btn.addChild(txt);
    btn.buttonMode = true;
    return btn;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a button object and style it in the way of a clickable text.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand your question! If it's a static text, then you can put a `LinkButton` or if it's a place where user can input text, then add an event listener for the textfield:

```
myTextField.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,clickListener);

function clickListener(e:Event):void
{
    // if a user clicks the textfield this function will be called
}
```

Comment: is link button control available with flash normally?
I know it is there in flex.